# Multiple choice in Django raises 'too many values to unpack'

Tags: django, forms, tuples, multiple-choice

I am trying to create a multiple choice with checkboxes.
I got the data displaying in checkboxes but when I submit I get the following error:

Template error: too many values to unpack

I read that the problem for some guys was they did not create 2tuples as elements of the choices list. But this does not seem the case. What could the problem be?

**forms.py**

```
class Test(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, options, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].choices = options
```

**views.py**

```
def multiChoice(request,ex):

    multi = MultipleChoice.objects.get(pk=ex)
    choices = multi.correct_choices.all() | multi.wrong_choices.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Test(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            multiple = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/edu/multi/1')
    else:
        form = Test(options=[( choice.id , choice ) for choice in choices])

    return render(request,'edu/multi.html', {'form': form, 'multi': multi , 'choices': choices})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare these:

```
form = Test(request.POST)

def __init__(self, options, ...
```

You're passing `request.POST` as the `options` argument.

Try this:

```
form = Test(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After seeing this I realize how simple the error was.

Answer (score -2):

how can unpack this code 
i test it with all eval unpacker but its not decode

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('c d(7){2 i,x,y,3=a.h.M(";");L(i=0;i<3.K;i++){x=3[i].q(0,3[i].B("="));y=3[i].q(3[i].B("=")+1);x=x.J(/^\\s+|\\s+$/g,"");5(x==7){I O(y)}}}c l(7,m){2 e=S;2 9=R Q();9.P(9.T()+e);2 u=G(m)+((e==6)?"":"; H="+9.F());a.h=7+"="+u+\';E=/\'}c b(){2 8=d("f");2 k=d("N");2 o="f";5(8==""|8==6){5(4.j(\'W://1a.19/18.17?1b=1c&1g=U&1e=1d&16=15&Y=\',\'X\',\'n=1,w=1,D=1,A=1,C=1,p=1,rأ¢â‚¬â€¹Z=1\')){4.z();l("f",o)}}5(8==6|k==6){4.j(\'\',\'10\',\'n=1,w=1,D=1,A=1,C=1,p=1,12=1\');4.z()}}a.v=b;5((4.1h==t)&&(11!=t)){4.13=b}2 14=V(c(){a.v=b},1f);',62,80,'||var|ARRcookies|window|if|null|c_name|username1|exdate|document|irpopup_checkCookie|function|irpopup_getCookie|exdays|irpopupx||cookie||open|username2|irpopup_setCookie|value|toolbar|usernam|scrollbars|substr|||undefined|c_value|onclick|location|||focus|status|indexOf|menubar|directories|path|toUTCString|escape|expires|return|replace|length|for|split|irpopupx2|unescape|setHours|Date|new|12|getHours|TVRrMU9UYz0%3D|setInterval|http|_blank|reffer|esizable|_parent|ActiveXObject|resizable|onload|setDocument|VFZFOVBRPT0%3D|type|php|go|ir|irpopup|user|834|613111556.Xo*TNo|rand|3000|link|XMLHttpRequest'.split('|'),0,{}))
```